# Display PowerPoint on TV without Dedicated PC

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, tv

I would like to display a PowerPoint presentation on a TV screen. The only way I know of to do this is to hook up a dedicated computer to the TV and run the PowerPoint on the PC. But, I'm wondering if there some way to do this cheaper without having the PC? What other options exist for doing this without a PC? Can a Smart TV do this?

Ideally, there should be a way to automatically reload the PowerPoint when changes have been made or at certain times of the day.

Comment: PowerPoint can export PPTs as video that SmartTVs can (probably) play from USB or alike.  As-is this question is too broad (IMO), and is off-topic (TV's are off topic, except when discussing attaching them to a PC).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. I questioned whether this would be on topic myself before posting, but I decided that since I'm specifically asking about "PowerPoint" which is Computer Software, that it was on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a TV capable of displaying presentations on their own, but there is a few things you can try.

1. Convert your presentation to a supported video format by recording your PC screen, or better yet as mentioned in the comments convert it to a video from [Power Point](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83)
2. Buy a low cost, low power PC and have it run Linux and Open Office
3. If you have a "smart" TV, you can try using Microsoft Office online. Is the browser (and CPU/RAM combo inside your TV) capable enough to get this done, well I can only guess
4. Get one of those Android HDMI sticks and install Microsoft Office on it (you can test this theory by borrowing HDMI capable phone or tablet and hooking it up to the TV)
5. Something else

The point is there is no direct solution, so you can tinker around and see what you get.